# UIBarButtonItem not responding

Tags: xcode, ios5, uibarbuttonitem

I am creating some barbutton items programmatically, but the selector on tap of the first button is not getting invoked. I have the following code in my viewDidLoad now :

```
[super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   // self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;


    _defaultBarColor = self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;
    [self loadPreferences];


    self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]  initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    self.btnSpinner = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.spinner];

    self.btnRefresh = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshPressed:)];

    self.lblLastUpdate = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" " style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    [self.lblLastUpdate setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13], UITextAttributeFont,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
        self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.btnRefresh,self.flexibleSpace,self.lblLastUpdate,self.flexibleSpace, nil];



    self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];


    [self loadData];
```

What I have found so far is that if I set the selector of the Label ( second item in the Toolbar) to the selector of the first item, then the first items selector gets invoked.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

> You allocate the barbutton but you didnot set frame for barButton.
>
> After allocation set frame for the barButton.

```
btnSpinner.frame=CGRectMake(10,10,70,40);
```

Comment: I solved the issue myself. It was a weird problem to say the least. I found that if the text in the second element was longer, the action for the first Barbutton was not getting invoked. After I shortened the text, it started working fine. Thanks for the input though.